# Uploading Large Images inthe Background on Windows Phone and HTML 5

Tags: c#, html

I have a Windows Phone app and an HTML 5 app. Both of these apps are uploading large images (> 5mb) from a user's phone to my server. I've recently experienced that sometimes these images are only half way uploaded. I'm trying to identify how to remedy this. I've considered chunking up the file, which seems like a lot of work. At the same time, I'm not aware of any other ways of handling this.

The bottom line is, there are cases where my user leaves the app before the upload is finished. I would like to resume uploading the file when the user comes back into the app. In both cases, I have the image as a Base64 encoded string. I really think I'm going to have to chunk it up. However,  I wanted to see if anyone had a better idea before I go through this hassle.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Chunking is a good choice here. I've seen some web services that say anything over 5MB it is recommended to chunk. Here is some code that you can take a look at to help you get moving.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43272/Uploading-Large-Files-Through-Web-Service